# Votes restart from my local storage when i refresh and vote.

Tags: javascript, css, html

Title is confusing i guess, let me explain. 
As you can see here, i got a localstorage JS, but it got some bugs https://fiddle.jshell.net/tnvv0dds/5/

When you refresh the page, and vote again, votes start from 0. Can someone tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you had reinitialised counter to 0. See my solution below, I have moved the setting of the counter

https://fiddle.jshell.net/tnvv0dds/7/

And also the functions to be within document.ready, which prevents the global namespace from getting polluted.